# Start method of Process doesn't return to main thread

Tags: .net, vb.net

I'm using the following code to start an other process:

```
        Dim winProcess As New System.Diagnostics.Process
        With winProcess
            .StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = True
            .StartInfo.ErrorDialog = False
            .StartInfo.FileName = "C:\Temp\TestProcess.exe"
            .StartInfo.UseShellExecute = True
            .StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden
            .StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.Temp

            .Start()

            'Continues here immediately after Start(), except on 2 PC's.

        End With
```

The program that contains this code does work perfectly on 100+ different Windows PC's (several combinations of Vista/7/8 and 32/64 bits). It's a 32 bits program that uses .NET Framework 4.

So far, on 2 PC's the code doesn't work. The problem is that on these PC's the .Start() method doesn't return; so the program hangs on that step. From what the started process does, I can tell that the process is correctly started and running immediately after the Start() method is executed.

The two PC's are Windows 7/64 and 8.1/64.

At some point in the past the program didn't have this problem on those PC's. Something has happened on those PC's, but I can't tell what.

No virus/malware scanner and firewall is running on those PC's, just to be sure that those aren't the cause. Also the Windows logs don't reveal anything.

I can imagine that the above information will not be enough to determine the source of the problem. I just hoping that someone of you had this same problem.

NB: I'm also familiar with C#; so code example in C# are welcome also.

Comment: What happens if you start your process manually on those boxes.

Comment: Then they just work. As said, I can tell from the logs of the started process that the process is running immediately after Start().

Comment: Hard to do this blind, but I'd be looking for your app not wholly starting for some reason, perhaps sat in a dialog box or somesuch